# Which Android device has all possible orientation sensors

Tags: android-sensors, android

Looking for a device that give maximum possible combination of:

Accelerometer

Gyroscope

Rotation matrix

Linear acceleration

Magnetic field

Rotation vector

Or any other sensor which gives any data about 3D orientation.

OR: Are there devices that embed InvenSense MotionFusion chips?

I'm looking for a device which is already available for sale on market, however any confirmed information about any upcoming devices will help as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of Market apps, [AndroSensor](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fivasim.androsensor&feature=search_result) and [Sensor List](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.miian.android.sensors&feature=search_result) show actual phone sensors with running data. Good old Nexus One has [Accelerometer and Magnetic compass](http://www.thesearethedroids.com/2009/12/14/nexus-one-hardware-running-list/). I assume you want a gyroscope.

My year-old AT&T Galaxy S has a [couple of orientation sensors](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=720446) that *may* [add-up to 6 axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281095/yamaha-ms-3c-sensor-on-samsung-galaxy) but [not a true gyro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347143/which-android-phones-out-there-do-have-a-gyroscope). A [wealth of gyroscople links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774496/android-gyroscope-examples) are documented on SO and more details on Galaxy S [sensors here](http://androidfragmentation.com/database/v/dr/491990/oem/samsung/dm/SAMSUNG-SGH-I897/carrier/AT&T).

Max, let us know which device you settle on, please, and how it works out.

Apparently, Galaxy S2 has LOTS of sensors [Orientation type of the sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429884/orientation-type-of-the-sensor/7632059)

Answer (score 0):

My HTC Desire (aka the Nexus One) is an oldish device now and it has all the sensors needed to detect it's orientation in 3 dimensions (gyro) and movement therein (acceleration).

I suspect most phones have these sensors - they're commonly used in Apps and people tend not to use stuff which isn't widely available (like proper multitouch for example).

It must have some sort of light sensor as it has an automatic backlight adjustment too - tho I've never tried to access that for any development purpose.

In fact, those apps which demonstrate sensor values only show a blank against things like temperature sensors which I suspect few devices have!?

If you'd like me to check it for any other sensor value - let me know - but I've developed a few Apps which use those sensors widely so I know they do work...